# __str__ method on list of objects

Tags: python

New to python, trying to create a card deck and want to implement a printing method for print(deck) => that gives a printed list of my cards.

My class PlayingCard has a **str** method which works fine to print a single card.

But when I create my Deck.cards object (which is a list of PlayingCard objects), I can't seem to print all the cards at once.

Tried replacing **str** with **repr**. Tried returning a list of strings in **str**

```
from enum import Enum

class Value(Enum):

    Two = 2
    Three = 3
    Four = 4
    Five = 5 
    Six = 6
    Seven = 7
    Eight = 8
    Nine = 9
    Ten = 10
    Jack = 11
    Queen = 12
    King = 13 
    Ace = 14

class Suit(Enum):

    Spades = 1
    Hearts = 2
    Clubs = 3
    Diamonds = 4


class PlayingCard():

    def __init__(self,value,suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit


    def __str__(self):
        return '{} of {}'.format(Value(self.value).name, Suit(self.suit).name)

class Deck():

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards=[PlayingCard(val,suit) for val in Value for suit in Suit]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cards)
```

```
deck = Deck()
print(deck)
```

Returns

```
[<__main__.PlayingCard object at 0x000001875FEC0080>,
<__main__.PlayingCard object at 0x000001875FE9EE48>,
....
....
]
```

Comment: Code looks ok, you're just confusing `__str__` with `__repr__`. Beware that you can override `__repr__` but it's hacky, you're not strictly supposed to, it breaks pickling etc. But it's fine for getting your basic debugging working, then just move the `__repr__` code to `__str__` when you've gotten it working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to replace the `__str__` method of the `PlayingCard` class with a `__repr__` method:

```
class PlayingCard():

    def __init__(self,value,suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{} of {}'.format(Value(self.value).name, Suit(self.suit).name)
```

**Alternatively** you can change the `__str__` method in the `Deck` class to get the string representation of every card:

```
class Deck():

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards=[PlayingCard(val,suit) for val in Value for suit in Suit]

    def __str__(self):
        return str([str(card) for card in self.cards])
```

Then you get the correct output with:

```
...

deck = Deck()
print(deck)
```

Output:
(The 2nd way will add quotes around every printed card)

> [Two of Spades, Two of Hearts, Two of Clubs, Two of Diamonds, Three of
>   Spades, Three of Hearts, Three of Clubs, Three of Diamonds, Four of
>   Spades, Four of Hearts, Four of Clubs, Four of Diamonds, Five of
>   Spades, Five of Hearts, Five of Clubs, Five of Diamonds, Six of
>   Spades, Six of Hearts, Six of Clubs, Six of Diamonds, Seven of Spades,
>   Seven ofHearts, Seven of Clubs, Seven of Diamonds, Eight of Spades,
>   Eight of Hearts, Eight of Clubs, Eight of Diamonds, Nine of Spades,
>   Nine of Hearts, Nine of Clubs, Nine of Diamonds, Ten of Spades, Ten of
>   Hearts, Ten of Clubs, Ten of Diamonds, Jack of Spades, Jack of Hearts,
>   Jack of Clubs, Jack of Diamonds, Queen of Spades, Queen of Hearts,
>   Queen of Clubs, Queen of Diamonds, King of Spades, King of Hearts,
>   King of Clubs, King of Diamonds, Ace of Spades, Ace of Hearts, Ace of
>   Clubs, Ace of Diamonds]

When you call `__str__` on a `list` object, it will go through every element of the list and call `__repr__` on that object to get its representation.

So when you call `print(deck)`, you get:

```
--> deck.__str__()
--> str(self.cards)
--> [card.__repr__() for card in self.cards]
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, repr is supposed to return python code that can recreate the object.

The way I would do it is to use a NamedTuple for PlayingCard

```
from typing import NamedTuple
class PlayingCard(NamedTuple):
    value: Value
    suit: Suit
```

*Note that the type hints are optional but come quite handy.

Then NamedTuple already implements repr and str so you don't need to reimplement anything.